# user list table showing twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have list components:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import UserService from '../services/UserService'

const UserList = () => {

    const [users,setUsers] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        UserService.findAll().then((response)=>{
            setUsers(response.data)
            
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    },[users])  
   const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = useState();    
  
   const handleRowClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedUserId(id);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <h2 className='text-center'>Users</h2>
        <div>
            <table className='table table-bordered table-stripped'>
                <thead>        
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        users.map(
                            user => 
                                
                            <tr key={user.id} onClick={() => handleRowClick(user.id)} style={{backgroundColor: selectedUserId === user.id ? "lightblue" : ""}}>  
                                <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                                <td>{user.email}</td>
                                <td>{user.password}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary mx-2" to={"/users/save"}  state='Create' >New</Link>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary mx-2" to={'/update/'+selectedUserId}  state='Update'> Edit</Link>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary mx-2" to={"/update/"+selectedUserId}   state='Delete' >Delete</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
export default UserList;
//<Link className="btn btn-primary mx-2" to={"/users/save"}  onClick={() => setData('Create')} >New</Link>
```

It shows UserList twice:
[image]

I thought because of the React Strict Mode but it wasn't.

Why is my table showing twice? How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you using this component ? Can you share that ? I suspect it could be react-router route which might be messing up

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include all relevant code as part of a complete [mcve]. From the image it seems you are rendering this `UserList` component in ***two*** places in the app.

Comment: You can use a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) when giving a html/css/javascript [mre].